# What is a "pit metal rooftop"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Playing Matrix for some kids with audio description on. A line sounds to my ear like "Trinity sprints, up and down pit metal rooftops." What is a "pit metal rooftop"? Or is it "peat metal rooftop"? Neither makes much sense to me. And Google also doesn't return anything meaningful or relevant. The scene is Trinity running and hopping on corrugated sheet metal roofs.

The clip can be found [here](https://clyp.it/cv3vgj2a). I hear "pit". Did I hear it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Trinity sprints, up and down *peaked* metal rooftops" as contrasted with flat roofs.

Notice the vowel sound is "higher", not only longer in "peak" than in "pick" or "pit".